# Handle onKeyPress event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an input and I need to fetch data from the server by pressing 'Enter'

There is a little problem. When I start writing letters in the input, it shows me only 1 letter and doesn't let me write another letters. Like if I press 'a' it shows 'a', after that if I press 'b' it changes and shows 'b'. I need to write a name of the city but it shows only 1 letter. Probably stupid question and I missing something, but need help.

Code:

```
const App = () => {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleSetLocation = ({ target : { value } }) => {
    setLocation(value)
  }

  const getWeatherInfo = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === 'Enter') {
      dispatch(getWeather(location))
    }
    setLocation('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="weather__content">
      <Container fluid style={{ padding: '15px' }}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Field
              type="text"
              className="weather__input"
              id="input"
              value={location}
              onChange={handleSetLocation}
              onKeyPress={getWeatherInfo}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <WeatherInfo/>
          </Col>
        </Row> 
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code for Field:

```
const Field = ({ type, className, value, onChange, id, onKeyPress }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        type={type} 
        className={className} 
        id={id}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
      />
      <label 
        htmlFor="input" 
        className="weather__location"
      >
        Location
      </label>
    </>
  )
}

export default Field
```

Comment: Read your code (is this your code?) - you're calling `setLocation('')` every time a keyPress is handled and you're also calling `setLocation(value)` every time a `change` event is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting location to be an empty string on every keypress, so Location state will be an empty string every time you call onChange.

So a fix for this is removing the `setLocation("")` in `getWeatherInfo`